# O que fazer com perguntas que atraem muitas respostas equivocadas?

Tags: debate, perguntas, comportamento

Há um tempo postei "[Pode-se fazer o navegador "lembrar" de uma senha programaticamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418/pode-se-fazer-o-navegador-lembrar-de-uma-senha-programaticamente)", mas meio que me arrependi de tê-lo feito: a "base" da pergunta era bem objetiva - como invocar programaticamente a função do navegador de "lembrar a senha". Mas como o assunto é "segurança" - um tópico bastante contextual por natureza* - recebi muitas respostas e comentários tentando me "orientar" quanto a melhores práticas, querendo mais detalhes do meu *threat model* (que acabei postando, numa tentativa de melhorar as coisas), e por fim algumas respostas e comentários que "passam pela tangente" (i.e. até tentam ajudar, mas respondem a algo diferente do que foi perguntado).

Pensei se não seria melhor fechar essa pergunta de vez, ou excluí-la, sei lá, mas não me parece a ação mais correta. Do jeito que ela está escrita, é uma boa pergunta? Está objetiva o bastante? É *on topic* no site?

Caso a resposta seja "sim", o que fazer com esse fluxo de respostas equivocadas**? Continuar "dando manutenção" à pergunta (i.e. respondendo, comentando), deixar pra lá o que não ajuda, outra coisa? Veja bem que essa pergunta em particular é só um exemplo, se aceitarmos nesse site outras perguntas envolvendo "segurança" (e talvez outras tags semelhantes, contextuais), é muito provável que essa situação se repita, por isso quis colocar essa discussão "na pauta" agora.

* P.S. "Contextual" é diferente de "Subjetivo": discordo dos que votaram para fechar minha pergunta como "principalmente baseada em opiniões", e vendo o histórico de revisões notei que muitos concordam comigo.

** P.P.S. "Equivocadas" é diferente de "Erradas": a grande maioria das respostas e comentários está "correta" no seu próprio contexto, só não se adequa bem ao contexto da pergunta. Minha ação até agora foi o "*no vote*" - não achei apropriado nem votar contra (a resposta não "não é útil") nem sinalizar como "não é uma resposta" (pois trata-se de tentativas genuínas de responder à pergunta).

Comment: No momento não esquente muito. Eu mesmo estou fazendo perguntas complicadas (não no sentido de resolver o problema) para ver o que acontece. Esse tipo de pergunta vai nos ajudar a entender as dificuldades do site e achar uma solução. Estou comentando porque obviamente não tenho uma resposta ainda. Certamente algo terá que ser feito. A regra inicial é votar negativamente no que está errado. Mas ela pode não ser suficiente. Mas o pessoal está muito baseado no SO. Não podemos tratar as perguntas diferentemente como ocorre lá. Perguntas conceituais são mais subjetivas mesmo.

Comment: Eu acho que tive um problema parecido recentemente. A minha impressão é que o problema decorre da nossa própria intenção de evitar de ser "muito amplo" e exagerar na descrição da dúvida. No seu caso, talvez se a pergunta tivesse se resumido a "É possível invocar programaticamente a função do navegador de 'lembrar a senha'?" (sem entrar em detalhes do seu problema, propriamente dito), *talvez* não tivesse gerado tanto desvio. Ainda assim, não acho que a pergunta deva ser excluída. Toda informação lá é potencialmente útil, e as respostas "ruins" serão naturalmente desqualificadas.